# If measured value available in at t+1 then how to skip predicted value in neural network in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time, neural-network

Here I have a dataset with three inputs, X1, X2,X3 . So here I wrote the code for predict future value of X1.

here I have a one problem, I'm predicting the future value (t+1) of X1. So sometime I had real values at that time period. I want to tell that if real value available while running the neural network, then skip the predicted value at (t+1) then take the real value and predict next future value of X1.

I didn't have any idea how to clear this.
Here I wrote the more description for understand purpose:

This explanation is not related to my csv file and for the understanding purpose I wrote this:

```
time(t)     X1     X2   X3     predicted at(t+1)(every 60 min)
 0          63     0    0       60
60          63     0    2       90
120         104    11   0       100
180          -     10   8       93
```

As you are seen my first prediction value 60 at 7:00:00 a.m. but at 7:00:00 a.m I had my real value. So I want to `skip my first prediction value then run the neural network with real value of X1 and predict the next value of X1.`

> At 120 min I had real value and skip the predict value and run the neural network with real value of X1.
>
> But 180 min I didn't measure the actual value . So then add the predict value run the neural network with prediction value of X1 and predict next value for X1.

Here my x_train_n = 80%

and X_test_n = 20%

I wrote the code for run the neural network model. But I don't know how to write this code.

Please help me to solve this code?

my code:

```
data=data.values
scaler_x = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
x = np.array(x).reshape ((len(x),4 ))
x = scaler_x.fit_transform(x)
scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
y = np.array(y).reshape ((len(y), 1))
y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)
print("row",len(y))
train_end = 80
x_train_n=x[0: train_end ,]
x_test_n=x[train_end +1: ,]
y_train_n=y[0: train_end]
y_test_n=y[train_end +1:] 
x_train_n=x_train_n.reshape(x_train_n.shape +(1,))
x_test_n=x_test_n.reshape(x_test_n.shape + (1,))

n_time_steps = 3
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(num_time_steps,x_train_n.shape[2])))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(8))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(1))


 batchsize = 1
 model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam")

 #model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['accuracy'])
 history = model.fit(x_train_n,y_train_n, batch_size = batchsize,  nb_epoch=30,validation_data=(x_test_n, y_test_n),shuffle =True)


 pred1=model.predict(x_test_n)
 model.reset_states()
 pred1 = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(pred1).reshape ((len(pred1), 1)))
 real_test = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(y_test_n).reshape ((len(y_test_n), 1))).astype(int)
 real = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(y_train_n).reshape ((len(y_train_n), 1))).astype(int)
 pred1 = pred1[:,0]
 real_test = real_test[:,0]
```

I tried once , but it gave me an error:

```
xr = iter(range(0, len(x_train_n[x_train_n.columns[0]])))
for i in xr:
   print(i)
   if i == pred1.all():
    next(xr)
```

Error is :
 [image: Error image]

[MY CSV FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit?userstoinvite=talktovipin@gmail.com&ts=5d26fa26&actionButton=1#gid=1512153575)